# Validate using Required property in JDeveloper

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

How to write the expression where a date is greater than another date within the same row by using the Expression Builder from the Property Inspector.

My trying: 
required="#{row.DateA gt row.DateB}"

is it correct?

Comment: Welcome Joseph, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question with a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and we'll show you how to do that.

Comment: Your trying look correct to me. Is it working? Do you have an error ?

Comment: No error but it's just not working as I expected. The inputtext within the row didnt show required when DateA is greater than DateB. what i want to do is a inputtext column need to appear mandatory when dateA > dateB